# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo in a Fragment during using SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, fragment, sharedpreferences

It doesn't happen often, but I've got 2 reports on this in Google Play console. here's the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.nikeabooks.eastermessage/ru.nikeabooks.eastermessage.BookActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4822)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at ru.nikeabooks.eastermessage.BookPageFragment.onCreate(BookPageFragment.java:66)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1455)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:893)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1872)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:215)
at ru.nikeabooks.eastermessage.BookActivity.onCreate(BookActivity.java:63)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
... 11 more
```

and here's the code (some of it):

```
public class BookPageFragment extends Fragment {

          SharedPreferences sPref;
//....some more code

      static BookPageFragment newInstance(int page) {
          BookPageFragment pageFragment = new BookPageFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
        pageFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return pageFragment;
      }

  @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);
        context=BookActivity.getContext();
        sPref=context.getSharedPreferences("ru.xxxxxx.xxxx.PREF", context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//and more
```

So, the `sPref=context.getSharedPreferences("ru.xxxxxx.xxxx.PREF", context.MODE_PRIVATE);` line is causing crash.. sometimes. for the most of the times it is working fine.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

`BookActivity.getContext();` looks suspicious. Try this

```
getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: static public Context getContext(){
 return context;
}

Comment: "sometimes. for the most of the times it is working fine." this means, that the context of your activity is nulled. Could be that the activity is finished so that the context is not reachable with the static way

Comment: @user2976267, do something like `if(context == null) { ... get the context somewhere else }`

Comment: I'll try. but it's hard to find the result out because it happens somewhere at some user who installed this app. I can't repeat this error